# Labeling data frame from other data frame

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have two data frames as follows:

```
 df1:
       id        f1      f2     f3    
       d2        34      3      5    
       d2        22      4      6     
       d3        37     3.2     6     
       d3        6.3     7      8    
       d3        12      8      3.6       
       d5        13      9      11
       d5        13      9      11  
            ...   ..     ..     ..
       d1500     12      12     32


 df2:
       id       label1      label2    labe3    
       d1         0            1       1    
       d2         1            1       0     
       d3         1            0       0     
       d4         1            1       0
       d5         0            1       0       
       d6         0            0       1
              ...      ...   ...
       d1500      1            1       1
       d20000     1            1       0
```

In the first data frame (df1), I have around 300000 rows with repeated ids, while in the second data frame (df2), I have only 20000 rows with unique ids. I want to add three columns as 'label1', 'label2' and 'label3' in df1 from the df2, where the two ids are matched.  E.g., I want to label ids in df1 where their ids are in df2.  So my desired dataframe shuld be like this:

```
   df1_with_label:
             id        f1      f2    f3   label1    label2  label3  
             d2        34      3     5        1        1        0
             d2        22      4     6        1        1        0
             d3        37     3.2    6        1        0        0
             d3        6.3     7     8        1        0        0
             d3        12      8     3.6      1        0        0
             d5        13      9     11       0        1        0
             d5        13      9     11       0        1        0
            ...   ..     ..   ..
            d1500      12      12    32       1        1        1
```

I could do it through for loop (the code is below), but it takes hours to finish this integration. Is there any way to do it much faster?

```
 df_new=df1.copy()
 df_new[['label1','label2','label3']]=0   #generate 0 value for the new columns  
 for id_df1 in range(df1.shape[0]):
    for id_df2 in range(df2.shape[0]):
       if df1['id'][id_df1]==df2['id'][id_df2 ]:
          df_new['label1'][ids]=df2['label1'][chs].copy()
          df_new['label2'][ids]=df2['label2'][chs].copy()
          df_new['label3'][ids]=df2['label3'][chs].copy()
```

Comment: check `join` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: `df1.join(df2, on='id')`

Comment: I am receive this error : **You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat**

Comment: strange, use `df1['id'] = df1['id'].astype(str)` and `df2['id'] = df2['id'].astype(str)` then try again

Comment: I checked the type of the columns, both of them are 'object', but again I received the same error. I tried this code: `merged_inner = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='id')`_. It works, but it returned more rows when I compared before integrations.
'